# Determine if redirect will produce a 404 status code in view prior to redirecting

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, http-status-code-404

I have a system in which the majority of functionality is dependent upon a session cookie being set by the user. Naturally with this, I allow easy changing of this session (a Property) so the user can view new information seamlessly as they are going throughout the application.

For example, a user is viewing Units in the system, when they select a new Property the Units for the newly selected Property are shown. Simple enough. However, there is an instance where a user is viewing a Unit and they change a Property. Obviously the Unit they are viewing is no longer found so the page 404's.

What I want is to know that the redirect will 404 so I can redirect them to the homepage instead. How can I do this?

Every way I can think to check (i.e. resolve or HttpRespsonse) does not show an error.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

import requests
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse, resolve, Resolver404

from apps.properties.models import Property

def set_property_session(request, property_id):

    redirect_url = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    # to check if it resolves, we must gather the path from the url
    path_to_check = urlparse(redirect_url).path
    try:
        # check to ensure the path resolves
        resolve(path_to_check)
        response = HttpResponse(path_to_check)
        # 200, not 404, when it should be while I am testing
        print(response.status_code)
        print(f'{path_to_check} is a valid path for redirection, we are going to go there in a sec...')
    except Resolver404:
        # error so go back home
        redirect_url = reverse('home', args=[client_url])
        print(f'{path_to_check} is not a valid path')
        return redirect(redirect_url)

    # 0 means the user wants to clear their session
    if property_id == 0:
        request.session['property'] = None
        Logger.info('property session set to none')
    else:
        # set the session to whichever property the user wants
        request.session['property'] = get_object_or_404(Property, pk=property_id)

    return redirect(redirect_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `resolve` function only checks if the url is a valid url as defined in your url rules. For example, if the `Property` url would look like this

```
url(r'^property/(?P<id>[-\w.]+)', Property.as_view(), name='property')
```

or

```
path('property/<str:id>', Property.as_view(), name='property')
```

and you only have one instance of `Property` with id 1, both following urls will resolve since they are valid urls according to the rules:

> property/1
>
> property/4

So, in your code, `resolve(path_to_check)` will always properly resolve since the `HTTP_REFERER` will always be a valid url (if not changed).
`response = HttpResponse(path_to_check)` just creates a 200 [see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects), which means that no `Resolver404` would be thrown at this point.

I think the only way that you can "resolve" this, is to handle it inside your view and return a redirect instead, or in this function, after you get your property, check if your property and unit ids match and handle it accordingly.
I am pretty sure that you could use related objects to handle this as seen [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/)